# Extension firefox return null value(console.log)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.setProperty("overFlow", "auto", "important")
document.querySelector('html').removeAttribute('class')
```

```
let toogleC = document.getElementById('checkbox)
```

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', (e) => {localStorage.setItem('value', e.target.checked)})
```

```
localStorage.getItem('value') === 'true' ? toogleC.checked = true : false
```

This console.log return null

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
const clearHtml = e.currentTarget.body.id
let valid = toogleC.checked
console.log(valid)//return null in browser and return value in js debug...
if (clearHtml !== 'clear') {e.target.style.setProperty('display', 'none')}})
```

```
See HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clear Web</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="front.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="back.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body id="clear">
    <h1>Clear??</h1>
    <div>
        <label class="switch" id="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried putting this value in a variable outside the addlistener. I feel like I can't access this value in the addlistener. As a reminder, this is a firefox extension.

Comment: "As a reminder, this is a firefox extension." --- So why the "google-chrome-extension" tag?

Comment: i test for firefox first. I start test this extension in chrome, i have the same problem

Comment: The 4th code block is incorrect. It should be toogleC.checked = localStorage.getItem('value') === 'true'

Comment: I tried, not works...
it's strange, it works on localhost but when i charged him on about:debugging on firefox it don't works

Comment: perhaps a problem with my manifest.json for access to this variable?

Comment: i do not have acces to extension localstorage in browser(Firefox or chrome)

Answer (score 0):

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Clear web",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Clear web",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "sketch/front.js",
                "sketch/back.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "sketch/back.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/Pat.png",
        "default_popup": "sketch/popup.html",
        "default_title": "Clear web",
        "browser_style": true
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "sketch/popup.html"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).